# mysql_real_escape_string does not escape "

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysql-real-escape-string

In PHP, I am escaping characters before insert in a MySQL database using mysql_real_escape_string

```
$array_to_insert = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $my_arr);
$mysql->setTbl("mytable");
$id = $mysql->insertArray($array_to_insert);
```

When saving, double quotes are being saved as escaped with a `\`. I do not want this, since some of the data is HTML and it may contain tags like `<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">` etc, which will be saved as `<a href=\"www.stackoverflow.com\">` and then displayed incorrectly in a WordPress setup.

I have read elsewhere on stackoverflow that to avoid escaping the double quotes, one must first insert (as above) then select and insert into a table again.

Is there a way to solve this issue without having to select and re-insert?

Thanks
(note: the database I am using is in utf-8 format)

Comment: Where did you read that insert/select/insert? That's a terrible solution - simshaun's answer should just about cover it, since this does smell of a double-escaping issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always strip slashes on the way out using http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

for instance:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or mysql_error();
while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo stripslashes($output['column_name']);
}
```

alternatively, just remove all escaped double quotes:

```
echo str_replace('\"', '"', $output['column_name']);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your server may have magic_quotes enabled. Check it with

```
var_dump( get_magic_quotes_gpc() );
```

Otherwise, it's probably something you are doing beforehand or that your db library is doing. `mysql_real_escape_string` only escapes the string so that it is safe to use in a SQL query. It can't help if the string is already escaped to begin with.

Comment: `magic_quotes` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. This is not the issue!